# What is the status of multiarch support in ROS 1 and/or 2?

Tags: ros, ros2, catkin, ros-kinetic, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Triggered by #q283547.

This may not be such a big issue any more with `i386` becoming less and less used, but I'm still curious.

Can somebody 'in the know' summarise the current status of multiarch support in ROS? The question that lead to my question is about ROS 1, but the same could be asked about ROS 2.

Searching around I found [ros/catkin#624](https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/624), which was merged and seems to address a piece of it in Catkin, and [catkin/catkin_tools#156](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/pull/156) for `catkin_tools`, but an `ls -al` of `/opt/ros/kinetic` on an `amd64` machine does not show an `x86_64-linux-gnu` sub dir in `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib`.

Is multiarch supported and would it depend on whether `GNUInstallDirs` is loaded in the respective `CMakeLists.txt`, or are there still some blocking issues that need to be resolved?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283945/what-is-the-status-of-multiarch-support-in-ros-1-and/or-2?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-28**:
Note that I tagged this with `kinetic`, but only because I had to pick something. It's not specific to that ROS release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Multi-Arch control fields aren't included in the bloom packaging templates for debian so there's no explicit support for multiarch per the Debian and Ubuntu documentation. Nor are different architectures of ROS packages co-installable.

Multiarch support is not a planned feature on the ROS 2 Roadmap. A few packages that use a multiarch installation from upstream are packaged in ardent to use newer versions than are available on xenial. Those packages required changes to packaging configuration in their reverse-dependencies in order to support GNUInstallDirs. These changes are still made on a per-package basis and there aren't current plans to try and generically add them to bloom's templates.

> Is multiarch supported and would it depend on whether GNUInstallDirs is loaded in the respective CMakeLists.txt, or are there still some blocking issues that need to be resolved?

I'm not confident on all the necessary details but I'm pretty sure that for a start: a ROS package attempting to use GNUInstallDirs would need to also register environment hooks to make sure the multiarch dir is on the library path.

One blocking issue I can think of off the top of my head, which to my knowledge are not even generally [solved upstream](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec#Co-installable_-dev_packages), are the handling of headers and dev dependencies in a multiarch setting. Since ROS packages don't separate dev dependencies into separate packages, this pretty much blocks multiarch support unless we either resolve the co-installability satisfactorily or separate dev packages out.

I believe the pull requests linked above are about supporting upstream dependencies with multiarch configuration (console-bridge and urdfdom) and not adding multiarch to ROS packages but I could be wrong about the scope.

Edit: Finished a sentence in the final paragraph.

Edit2: Formatting to reveal link.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2018-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-01**:
Is the `[1]` missing a link?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-01**:
Thanks for the answer.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-03-01**:\

> Is the [1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec#Co-installable_-dev_packages) missing a link?

Looks like answers doesn't support the full range of markdown I'm familiar with. Edited to show the link.